# web-based hardware configuration page (for changing my network settings in debian)

Tags: php, apache, configuration, debian

I have a hardware(with Debian distribution) and I want a web based user interface(like ADSL modem configuration webpage) that change my network settings (/etc/network/interfaces file). I need to know best practices (using PHP or any language that you suggest) in term of security and possibility.

thanks a lot

Comment: Best security practice is to **never do this**.

Comment: so how we configure our wireless modem?@ceejayoz

Comment: Chances are your wireless modem's web control panel is buggy, insecure, and horribly user unfriendly. Happily, they're usually at least access-limited to the LAN.